# How can PHP gracefully shut down a local socket connection...?

Tags: php, linux, sockets, polling, unix-socket

I have a PHP client connecting to a local C server programme via a text-only Unix-domain socket. However, the only way I can get it to shutdown nicely is if I finish the socket session with:

```
stream_socket_shutdown($sock, 1); // shutdown socket writing
usleep(500 * 1000);           // wait for 0.5 seconds
fclose($sock);                // actually close the socket (finally)
```

I'd like to shut it down gracefully like my C client:-

```
shutdown(connection_fd, SHUT_WR);     // tell server we've stopped sending queries
// Read from the socket until poll(connection_fd) yields POLLRDHUP / POLLHUP / POLLERR / POLLNVAL
shutdown(connection_fd, SHUT_RDWR);   // tell connection we've stopped listening
close(connection_fd);                 // close the whole connection (finally)
```

However, PHP doesn't appear to have a direct socket poll() equivalent. How can I get PHP to shut down my local socket gracefully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried **[stream_set_blocking()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php)** ?  If you set the stream to be non-blocking, you should be able to consume all of the pending data before closing the connection:

```
socket_shutdown($sock, STREAM_SHUT_WR); 
stream_set_blocking($sock, 0);
while( fgets($sock) !== false ) { ; }
fclose($sock);
```

**Edit:** used constants, and fixed the set-blocking command to use the correct value.

**Explanation:** By setting the stream to non-blocking and then reading everything from it, we consume all of the data already in the input buffer.  This greatly speeds up the shutdown process by signaling the peer that our buffers are clear and he can send us more messages (like the FIN packets).

It is still possible to get a slow shutdown, but much less likely.

Comment: Aha - you're 99% right. If you change the first line to 'socket_shutdown($sock, 0);' (which is what you meant :-) ) then it indeed seems to shut the single connection down gracefully. However, I'm unsure whether this will work as intended when multiple connections are active - I don't really want my PHP actively spinning waiting. So perhaps this isn't the full answer... would you agree?

Comment: It won't actually spin-wait, because the socket is in non-blocking mode.  What will happen instead is all of the pending data will be read without waiting for the other end to send any more data, which speeds up the shutdown operation in nearly all cases.

Comment: I completely agree that all of the data already sent will arrive. However, if in order to respond the server has to get some data from (for example) an attached I2C device, there can be a significant delay between the client sending the query and the server responding. I'm guessing that in those (frequent) situations, the PHP will spin-wait, which I'd rather avoid if possible. I'm guessing that I'll end up building a combination of non-blocking fgets() calls and usleep()s to do the trick here.

Comment: Yeah.  It isn't perfect.  Just better.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, looks like I can engineer an answer now. :-)